# Upload image from ReactJS to Firebase v9 Storage

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-storage

I am running into a problem. I want to create a simple image upload input and the images should be stored in a Firebase Storage. I think I have mixed up some v8 and v9 code, but I can't also find a right answer.

When I trigger the upload, I get this error message:

```
TypeError: _firebase_firebase__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.storage.ref is not a function
```

```
  61 | 
  62 | const uploadFiles = () => {
  63 |   //
> 64 |   const uploadTask = storage.ref(`images/${img.name}`).put(img);
     | ^  65 |   uploadTask.on(
  66 |     "state_changed",
  67 |     (snapshot) => {
```

This is my code I am running:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { storage } from "../../firebase/firebase";
import { ActionBtn, Topbar, SubjectHead, CardList } from "../../components/styles";

const CreateImg = () => {
  const [img, setImg] = useState(null);
  const [progress, setProgress] = useState(0);

  const formHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const file = e.target.files[0];
    setImg(file);
  };

  const uploadFiles = () => {
    const uploadTask = storage.ref(`images/${img.name}`).put(img);
    uploadTask.on(
      "state_changed",
      (snapshot) => {
        const prog = Math.round(
          (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100
        );
        setProgress(prog);
      },
      (error) => console.log(error),
      () => {
        storage
          .ref("images")
          .child(img.name)
          .getDownloadURL()
          .then((url) => {
            console.log(url);
          });
      }
    );
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Topbar>
        <SubjectHead>Create New CV</SubjectHead>
        <ActionBtn onClick={createCv}>Create CV</ActionBtn>
      </Topbar>
      <CardList type="form">
        <div>
          <div>
            <input
              type="file"
              accept=".jpg,.png,.jpeg"
              onChange={formHandler}
            />
            <button type="button" onClick={uploadFiles}>
              Upload
            </button>
            <h4>{progress}%</h4>
          </div>
      </CardList>
    </div>
  );
};

export default CreateImg;
```

Here is my config file:

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getStorage } from "firebase/storage";

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "XXX",
  authDomain: "XXX",
  projectId: "XXX",
  storageBucket: "XXX",
  messagingSenderId: "XXX",
  appId: "XXX",
};

const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const storage = getStorage(app);

export { storage };
```

I would be super happy if someone could help me with my issue.

Comment: Is `import { storage } from "../../firebase/firebase";` correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your imports:

```
import { getStorage, ref } from "firebase/storage";
```

Then create the ref:

```
const storage = getStorage();
const storageRef = ref(storage, `images/${img.name}`); //note that ref is not a function on storage -- it's a separately imported function
```

Set the metadata:

```
const metadata = {
  contentType: 'image/jpeg'
};
```

Start and monitor the upload:

```
const uploadTask = uploadBytesResumable(storageRef, file, metadata);

uploadTask.on('state_changed',
  (snapshot) => {
    //etc
```

More documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files#upload_files

Comment: Thanks for your help, I am new to Firebase and still confuse things. Now I am running into another problem. 
`POST 400`
`FirebaseError: Firebase Storage: An unknown error occurred, please check the error payload for server response. (storage/unknown)`

Comment: Okay, the other Error message I could solve. Thanks a lot, you truly helped me.